# Find unique values from a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have several categories, and would like to determine if they are unique or not.

[image]

Under the `Unique` column I have my expected value. The `Tried` colum has the "tried" formula inside.

I tried:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;B2:B6;0;TRUE);"NOT UNIQUE")
```

However, this gives me `NOT UNIQUE` in every row.

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` can't be used to determine uniqueness.  An alternative approach is to use `COUNTIFS` to count number of occurances, if it's greater than 1 then item is not unique

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6;B2)=1;B2;"NOT UNIQUE")
```